# insert text in cell after finding row

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I need a google apps script doing the following: (example titles)
1. Find a row in "sheet A" based on text in a cell in "Sheet B"
2. When this row is found, insert an "x" in column A in that found row.

Then I need another script that does the same thing, except removes the "x" and not adding it.

I hope someone can help me.

Cheerio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one function is required. First you write an 'x' and then you write a ''. I included two test functions.

```
function putTest()
{
  simpleSearch('SheetA','SheetB','x')
}

function removeTest()
{
  simpleSearch('SheetA','SheetB','')
}

function simpleSearch(targetSheet,critSheet,data,targetCol,critRowrng)
{
  var targetCol = (typeof(targetCol)!='undefined')?targetCol:1;
  var critRowrng = (typeof(critRowrng)!='undefined')?critRowrng:'B2';
  var data = (typeof(data)!='undefined')?data:'x';
  var targetSheet = (typeof(targetSheet)!='undefined')?targetSheet:'';
  var critSheet = (typeof(critSheet)!='undefined')?critSheet:'';
  if(targetSheet && critSheet)
  {
    var targetSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(targetSheet);
    var critSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(critSheet);
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid Sheet Names');
    return;
  }

  var targetRow = critSht.getRange(critRowrng).getValue();
  var targetRng = targetSht.getRange(targetRow, targetCol);
  targetRng.setValue(data);
}
```

Not sure why I called it simple search but you can rename it if you like.